# Sharing files across weblogic clusters

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a weblogic 12 cluster. Files get pushed to it both through http forms and through scp to a single machine on the cluster. However I need the files on all the nodes of the cluster. I can run scp myself and copy to all parts of the cluster, but I was hoping that weblogic supported the functionality in some manner. I don't have a disk shared between the machines that would make this easier. Nor can I create a shared disk.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No There is no way for WLS to ensure a file copied on one instance of WLS is copied to another. Especially when you are copying it over even using scp.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a shared storage mount, so that all managed servers can refer to this location with out the need to do SCP.